# Grizzly 2.4.4 Closed WebSockets Memory Leak

Tags: websocket, memory-leaks, grizzly

I was asked to analyze heap dump that caused out of memory on environment. 
The project is using grizzly 2.4.4 websockets module.

The issue is that under high load (websocket connections) - when connections are both created and closed frequently - old closed connections are not garbage collected and cause a memory leak.

In heap dump I noticed the same pattern for all of these closed websockets - they are referred somehow by live (connected) websocket (starting at GC root) through it's protocolHandler->filterChainContext->TcpNIOConnection indexed attributes.

This looks like chaining:
**connected_websocket**->protocolHandler->filterChainContext->tcpNioConnection->attributes->websocketHolder->**old_closed_websocket**->....

Looking at code I didn't understand how this is actually possible - shouldn't TcpNIOConnection instances be independent and not refer each other?

Here is the screenshot from heap dump which is more explanatory:
[image]

Notice the EmsWebSocket (it extends DefaultWebSocket - nothing special in it) at the bottom. This is the connected websocket. And it refers multiple websocket holders and TcpNIOConnections in a row which are all closed. How is it possible to reproduce this at all? I tried locally but without success.

It would be really great if someone of grizzly developers could comment on this.

Thanks in advance,